# Access to the path is denied with the correct app.manifest settings

Tags: c#, winforms, access-denied

I have a strange problem. I have this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Shorko\Desktop\mobile-store", "*.rar",
                                     SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
        {
            string path = "E://yo";                               
            File.Move(filePaths[i], path);
        }                      
    }
```

I also created the app.manifest file and changed one of the lines to:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

But I'm still getting the same error! I know there are tons of posts like this,but I can't get it working.

Comment: Did you check the other two dozen posts with this same title that appear in the `Related` list to the right (-->>>>>)? Surely one of them has an answer that you could use instead of posting yet another duplicate of the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[File.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) requires two filenames, a source filename and a destination file name.
Doesn't work if the destination is a directory.

```
string path = "E://yo";                                
for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++) 
{ 
     File.Move(filePaths[i], Path.Combine(path, Path.GetFileName(filePaths[i])); 
}
```